# Does this work?

Tags: linux, bash

I haven't got Linux on my computer at the moment, so I was wondering if someone can test this code I wrote.

It is supposed to rename a file extension when you type something like this, to run it, into the terminal:

chaxxx zzz yyy *.zzz

"chaxxx" being the name of the file.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
>>deleted<<
```

Comment: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [online compiler & interpreter](http://ideone.com/) for your tests. [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/) supports Bash Script too.

EDIT:

It does work. *ren.sh* is your script name, here you go:

```
$ ls
asdf.doc  ren.sh  text.txt

$ ./ren.sh txt doc *.txt
text.txt
text

$ ls
asdf.doc  ren.sh  text.doc
```

Comment: I've also tested it with multiples files. It's Ok.

Comment: It would work too. Just strip the extension, change the permission of the file with `chmod a+x ren` and put it in some place like `/usr/local/bin` to be accessible to your user at all times.

Comment: You need to review your questions and accept some answers! Including this one.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the `rename` command?  You are pretty much reinventing the wheel here.

#### From `man rename`

> rename .htm .html *.htm
>
> ```
>    will fix the extension of your html files.
> ```

#### Edit

If you are going to do it yourself in `bash` then I would suggest the following code instead. Here are its benefits:

1. It handles files with spaces in
   their names
2. It checks to see if the file it's about to modify actually
   ends in the extension you want to
   change before it attempts to `mv`
   it.
3. It uses native Parameter Expansion syntax rather than call the external binary `basename`
4. It checks to see if the # of input parameters is at least 3, otherwise it echos a usage message and exits
5. It uses a for-loop with indirection rather than calling the `test` with `shift`

---

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( $# < 3 )); then
  echo "Usage: $0 oldExt newExt files"
  exit
fi

EXTf=$1
EXTt=$2

for (( i = 3; i <= $#; i++)); do
  NAME=${!i}
  if [[ "${NAME##*.}" == "$EXTf" ]]; then
    mv "$NAME" "${NAME%.*}.$EXTt"
  fi
done
```

Comment: And in the process you don't support filenames with spaces on them, not to even talk about filenames starting with a dash.

Comment: @Mr Teeth: see my update

Comment: @Mr Teeth No worries, it only killed 2 mins out of my life. Ive wasted 2 mins doing much more useless things